# Strange layout rendering when edit text gains focus

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment with a listview and an edittext.
When the `edittext` gains focus all the layout except the edittext turns black for one second.

If I hold the edittext clicked then the surrounding layout stays black until I scroll the list, or touch the screen, it only happens on Jelly Bean 4.1.2.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49.33dp"
        android:background="@color/grey">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbox"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:ems="8"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_layout"
        android:divider="@color/light_blue"
        android:dividerHeight="0.67dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can be the causes for that behavior ?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your listview(in xml) and try..

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Hope it works!!

Comment: It is not related to the scrolling of the list, the scroll is smooth and is not blinking.